# Img object src value return wrong value for base64 on nextjs api,how to fix?

Tags: image, next.js, base64

I am making the backend for a project I cant make a frountend on and it is getting tricky with base64 for the imags!

I have an array full of images from the public folder in my nextjs app. It is in a separate file and i have 2 functions that dose base64 for me.

one of them dose a 4 loop through the files and puts them into the 2nd function! the puts the result into a new array and takes it to my db to be show as a response.

the other converts to base64.

but no matter what path i put in it (a path i made myself or in my array it gives wrong path!

the src paths from my images they store in nextjs cache and they give a next folder path!

like this '[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:_next\static\media\1.86fccbdb.jpg']'

but when i go to the .next path it is there in the correct spot!

here is my code

```
import { imagesPath } from "@/testdata/imagesArray";
const fs = require('fs');
const base64Img = require('base64-img');


export default async function getFile64s(){
  const result = []

  for (const file of imagesPath) {
    const image64 = await convertToBase64(file.src)
    
    result.push(image64);
  }

  return result
}


function isPathValid(path) {
  try {
    fs.accessSync(path);
    return true;
  } catch (error) {
    return false;
  }
}

async function convertToBase64(file){
  const check = isPathValid(file)
  console.log(check)
  //C:\Users\prodi\OneDrive\Desktop\photo gal\photogal\.next\static\media\1.86fccbdb.jpg
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    base64Img.base64(file, (error, data) => {
      if (error) {
        reject(error);
      } else {
        resolve(data);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is a very specific error so I will tell you what is happening first

first
when you have an array of imported images in nextjs(might work for others) when you console.log it in a for loop it will give an object instead of the path!

this at least happened for me! the object vars dont matter except the src var!

this variable is important

now this is where it gets specific!

I am using nextjs so the src looks something like this

```
/_next/static/media/6.d33b3fad.jpg
```

this looks like a fine path right it should work right! No it dosent if you use it you will get an ugly ENOENT, no such file or directory error.

we dont want this

firstly if you inspect the error message closely more at the end the last path will tell you itself again but this time it has a C: at the start!

you dont want this usually when you see that it is looking for a big path that gives you base computer as a root!

so what you need to do is find the root! Well how do i do that im lazy?!

just go to the .next js folder and follow you previous route

```
 /_next/static/media/6.d33b3fad.jpg
```

this one

so

next
static
media
yourfile

then right click and copy the path to it (not relative path)

it should look something like mine

mine:

```
C:\Users\prodi\OneDrive\Desktop\photo gal\photogal\.next\static\media\1.86fccbdb.jpg
```

now you see this path

as soon as it says /.next remove the rest of the end so it will look like this

```
'/Users/prodi/OneDrive/Desktop/photo gal/photogal'
```

see how it removed the path that your img src says

this part that i just showed you is one part of the path

lets save it and call it FirstPart

now you know that other path you have?
this one

```
 /_next/static/media/6.d33b3fad.jpg
```

we will combine this path with the other one BUT NOT YET

something still needs to be done

If you are only doing one file you could just have pasted the relative path in but we are doing a for loop so we cant do this

get this code

```
    function replaceUnderscoreWithDot(string) {
  return string.replace(/_/g, '.');
}
```

and paste it in your app

then put this path

```
/_next/static/media/6.d33b3fad.jpg
```

in the function

and store it in a var lets call this var SeccondHalf

now the final path is

FirstPart + SeccondHalf

you can combine those just like that then boom the path works

my code

```
   import { imagesPath } from "@/testdata/imagesArray";
const fs = require('fs');
const base64Img = require('base64-img');


export default async function getFile64s(){
  const result = []

  for (const file of imagesPath) {
    const image64 = await convertToBase64(file.src)
    
    result.push(image64);
  }

  return result
}


function isPathValid(path) {
  try {
    fs.accessSync(path);
    return true;
  } catch (error) {
    return false;
  }
}

function replaceUnderscoreWithDot(string) {
  return string.replace(/_/g, '.');
}

async function convertToBase64(file){
  const check = isPathValid(file)
  //console.log(check)
  //C:\Users\prodi\OneDrive\Desktop\photo gal\photogal\.next\static\media\1.86fccbdb.
  console.log(file)
  const newfile = replaceUnderscoreWithDot(file)
  const test = '/Users/prodi/OneDrive/Desktop/photo gal/photogal'
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    base64Img.base64(test + newfile, (error, data) => {
      if (error) {
        reject(error);
      } else {
        resolve(data);
      }
    });
  });
}
```